# Typeahead AngularJS not "selecting" when clicked

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap-3

im using AngularJS + Bootstrap and this is my code to get the JSON from the server:

ps: pessoa = person

function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {

```
  $scope.selected = undefined;

$scope.getNomes = function(val) {
    return $http.get('/pessoa/buscarPor', {
      params: {
        nome: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function (res){

          pessoas = [];
          angular.forEach(res.data.list, function(item){
              pessoas.push(item.busca_formatada);
              });
    return pessoas;
    })
  };
```

and in the html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" typeahead="pessoa for pessoa in getNomes($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
```

it show the result, but when i click nothing changes or the field get filled

Comment: When you click **WHAT** what do you expect to change?  What field do you expect to get filled?  Can you provide a runnable sample to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: yesss, this, when i type Jeff, it show JeffryHouser, when clicked fill the "asyncSelected", im using this the typeahed from -> http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

the same example, i just changed the source of the json

Comment: It will be _very_ hard to help without a live reproduce scenario (ideally using http://plnkr.co/)...